# Gravity Forms Multipage Form, dynamically populate from existing form entry based on unique key

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm working with Gravity Forms (WordPress) on a pair of forms for a school. They have an initial form for **applications**. Each submission gets assigned a unique five character key to identify it. This is saved in a hidden field. This form has things like name, email, phone, address etc. This form is up and running, working great.

Once a student has been accepted, we now need to have another form that is for **registrations**. This form will be a multipage form with more detail and various questions about history/parents etc. My thought is that the first *page* contains a single field that asks for the key assigned to their application. Once this first page is submitted, the form would query the database based on the key and return any info from the original application that applies to the second form. So things like name, email, phone wouldn't have to be re-entered manually.

I'm starting down the road of dynamic population and running into some trouble. It appears things operate differently on multi-page forms, and depending on whether you're using AJAX or not. Has anyone had experience doing this kind of key lookup for form population? I could do this in vanilla PHP/MySQL without a problem, but the Gravity Forms stuff has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough and is left open for interpretation. However, since I ran into problems with multi-page gravitiy forms as well, and could find very little help online, here is my experience.

If you go from one page to the next, you can access field values from previous pages using `rgpost("input_" . YOUR_FIELD_ID);`. Checkbox collections are accessed by "input_".FIELD_ID."_".OPTION_INDEX. Dynamically filled dropdowns seemed to get reset in my experience. If this happens to you, before moving to the next page, you can copy any values from these fields into hidden fields, and read from the hidden fields.

Fields that already have a default value (`field->defaultValue`) are NOT updated even though the appropriate hooks are triggered. E.g: `add_filter('gform_field_value_my_field', 'populate_your_field')`. A dump of the value you return in populate_your_field will show a different value than when you inspect my_field, which is supposed to receive this value. my_field will retain the first value it received and wont change anymore.

This is a problem when your fields depend on input of fields from previous pages, and users go back and forth changing those. Your dependend fields wont update on any hook. I've tested extensively with gform_field_value, gform_pre_render, gform_field_validation and gform_post_paging.

I found one solution: echo a hidden div with data attributes in the gform_pre_render hook, and populate the fields through javascript.

`add_filter('gform_pre_render', 'dynamic_population', 10, 1);
function dynamic_population($form) {
    echo "<div id='my_data' style='display:none' data-myjsonarray='.json_encode(my_json_array).'></div>";
}`

In your gravity form, you can create a html field and add javascript in there.

`<script>
window.onload = function() {
    //custom function that fills given gform dropdown with given array
    fill_dropdown(
        jQuery('#input_1_1'),
        jQuery('#my_data').data('myjsonarray')
    );
}
</script>`

Hope this somehow helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms Populate Anything](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/) can handle this really well.

1. Add a field to your form where the user would enter their reference number.
2. Configure a field to be populated with the entry data based on the provided reference ID where it matches an entry that has the same reference ID:

   [image: https://gwiz.io/2UByMQB]

Answer (score 0):

Not the best and you can use Dave's Idea, he is from Gravity Wiz, I go to that forum for help sometimes. That said, I've done this with a combination of jQuery in WordPress to grab and set the values from other fields, store the values temporarily on localStorage to store the values in, and then the gform_pre_render in WordPress for Gravity Forms to update the value on the new form. On the final step you could also make shortcodes in Wordpress for every form id you want to do this with and pass  dynamic values via gform_pre_render function or pass it back from the cookie with JQuery to the field class you give it.